# Regular expression issue in javascript for validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have a regular expression in JavaScript which must have following condition.

1. Space is not allowed as a first character.
2. Repeated space is not allowed (e.g. - `Vineet  Rag` - FAIL, `Vineet Rag Mishra` - PASS).

Kindly help me to come up with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So let's break it down into pieces and then build it up.

1. Does not start with a space:

   var regExp = /^ /;
   var input = " abc";
   regExp.test(input)

When we run that, we see `true` on the console. If we run it again with this:

```
var regExp = /^ /;
var input = "abc";
regExp.test(input)
```

We see `false`.

2. Does not contain more than one space in a row:

I can use the `{min,max}` option to a character matcher like so: `[ ]{2,}` which is "two or more spaces".

var regExp = new RegExp(/[ ]{2,}/);
var input = "ab  c";
regExp.match(input);

Which returns `true` when run. If we change `input` to "ab c", it returns `false`.

**Putting them together**

This is the important part -- we want either 1 or 2. So we can use the `|` bar for "OR" like so:

```
var regExp = /^[ ]|[ ]{2,}/;
```

And a console run:

```
var regExp = /^[ ]|[ ]{2,}/;
undefined
regExp.test(' abc');
true
regExp.test('abc');
false
regExp.test('a bc');
false
regExp.test('a  bc');
true
```